# Search a vector with == operator

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class which looks like

```
class Element
{
public :
    Element(int im_index, int seg_index)
    {
        imIndx = im_index;
        segIndx = seg_index;
    }
    Element() { imIndx=-1 ; segIndx=-1; }

    void getData( int & toReturnImIndx, int & toReturnSegIndx )
    {
        toReturnImIndx = imIndx;
        toReturnSegIndx = segIndx;
    }

    // Specific for disjoint_sets
    size_t dsID;
    size_t dsRank;
    size_t dsParent;

    bool operator==(Element const& rhs);
    bool operator!=(Element const& rhs);
    bool compareByParent(Element const& rhs);

private:
    int imIndx;
    int segIndx;

};
```

Only thing to note is that I have defined an "==" operator.

Now, given a vector of `Elements` (`vector<Element>`) how to search an element in it. I am aware that it has a function `std::find`. This function asks the comparison function. How is it possible to specify the "==" operator.

I want to use it like

```
vector<Element> ele;
// populate the ele

Element tmp( 2,3 );
if( find( ele, tmp ) )
    cout<< "found" ;
else
    cout<< "not found";
```

Comment: Did you also declare a `bool operator==(Element const& lhs, Element const& rhs);` outside the class?

Comment: but I have one inside the class. Is it required to declare one outside too?

Comment: For (automatic) use with `find()`, you'll need also one as I have proposed.

Comment: But [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) should already use the `==` operator, so what problems do you have?

Comment: bool operator==(Element const& rhs); is opreator overloading you should declare whats happening in side that function outside or in side the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) takes three arguments. The first two are iterators that indicate the range in which to search. If you want to search an entire vector, pass the iterators returned by the `begin` and `end` member functions of the vector, respectively.

```
Element tmp( 2,3 );
if( std::find( ele.begin(), ele.end(), tmp ) != ele.end() )
    cout<< "found" ;
```

Note that you should declare your comparison operator const.

```
bool operator==(Element const& rhs) const;
```